# Fetching data from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysqli

I just created a page that could get the name of the students in 2 schools using their school name(This is just for my practice). But when i execute the following code i don't get the name of the top student in each school whose name is at top in the database, But i get the rest of the list.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['school']))
{
    $school = trim($_GET['school']);
    $people = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE school = ? ");
    $people->bind_param('s', $school);
    $people->execute();
    $people->bind_result($id, $name);

    if(!$people->fetch())
    {
        echo "Invalid School Name!!";       
    }   
    else
    {
        while($people->fetch())
        {
            echo 'ID. ',$id, ' ',$name,'<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This problem only occurs when i use if and else statements to output error message "Invalid School Name!!". If i just use the while loop to fetch data, i get the full list. Please tell me the why i miss the first name and a solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: @Prix No, `if (!$people->fetch())` is correct (partially)

Comment: Can you choose an answer if you're problem is solved? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the conditional to test against the result

```
$people->execute();
$people->store_result();
$people->bind_result($id, $name);

if($people->num_rows == 0)
{
    echo "Invalid School Name!!";       
}   
else
{
    while($people->fetch())
    {
        echo 'ID. ',$id, ' ',$name,'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first test does `$people->fetch()`. If the answer is not false, then it does it again and execute the code in the loop until the last element. So your if is the problem because it pass the first element while doing the test.

To solve this, just remove your if-condition: if the query doesn't find any people,

```
while( $people->fetch() ) {
 Do_something(); }
```

...will be jumped and everything will work as expected.

To add the error message, use a  try/catch  or check whether you entered the loop or not with a boolean (maybe there are other methods, though).

Comment: Not a `try/catch`, because it wouldn't throw an exception (it would return false).  Instead, just call `fetchAll()` once and test the `count()` of the resultant array. If it's zero, show the error, if it's nonzero, do a `foreach` over the array to output data.